# Заполнение динамического двумерного массива строками в Си

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь создать двумерный массив в Си, вроде как вышло. Если нет, то поправьте.

Столкнулся с проблемой в его заполнение, а именно не хочет заполняться. Программа выходит после того, как создается массив. Для проверки программы я вставил между созданием массива и его заполнением **printf("0");**, что дало мне то, что программа выходит после создания массива.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int size_y, i;
    
    printf("Введите число столбцов таблицы: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size_y);

    printf("Введите заголовки таблицы:\n");
    
    char** mass = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size_y);   //создание массива
    for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++)    
    {
        mass[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size_y * 100);  
    }
    printf("0");
    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; i++)    //заполнение массива
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < size_y; k++)
        {
            char str = gets();
            mass[i][k] = str;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("0");
    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; i++)    //проверка как заполнился массив
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < size_y; k++)    
        {
            puts(mass[i][k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите его заполнить строками.

Comment: Во-первых, `mass[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size_y * 100);` -- вы указали не тот размер ячейки выделяемой памяти, нужен `sizeof(char)`. Во-вторых, через вложенные циклы и `gets` вы пытаетесь засунуть строку в `char`. С `puts` та же история. В-третьих вы неправильно используете `gets`, [почитайте о ней подробнее](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/gets). Также строки в си не присваиваются. В-четвертых, лучше вообще не используйте `gets`, это небезопасная функция. В-пятых, подключите `string.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если макс длинна колонки известна на этапе компиляции - почему бы не читать в статический буффер и копировать в строку. Тогда динамической памяти будет ровно столько, сколько необходимо строчке.

Так же не забывайте очищать выделенную память во избежание утечек.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int size_y;
    
    printf("Cols: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size_y);
    printf("Cols names:\n");
    
    char** mass = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size_y);   //создание массива
    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; ++i)    //заполнение массива
    {
        char buff[101];
        scanf_s("%100s", buff, 100);

        mass[i] = strdup(buff);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; ++i)    //проверка как заполнился массив
    {
        printf_s("%s\n", mass[i]);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; ++i)
    {
        free(mass[i]);
        mass[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(mass);
    return 0;
}
```